# Returning a value inside a function

Tags: python

This has probably been asked to death, but i cant figure out how to do it.

This program opens a pdf and find a pattern of a string specified when running. It then prints out how many times the said string is found inside each pdf. What im looking to do is to add the number in "amountOfHits" with "totalHits" so i can find out how many of each instance there is total for example in a folder of pdfs.

This is the code:

```
import os
import re
import PyPDF2 as pypdf2

def pdf(name):
   try:
      pdfObject = f"{name}"
      readObject = pypdf2.PdfFileReader(pdfObject)
      pageContent = readObject.getPage(0)
      pageExtract = pageContent.extractText()
      amountOfHits = len(re.findall(rePattern, pageExtract))
      print(f"{pdfObject} contains {rePattern}: "+ str(amountOfHits) + " times.")
   except:
      return

rePattern = input("Pattern: ")
dirContent = os.listdir()
totalHits = 0
content = ""

for x in range(len(dirContent)):
   content = dirContent[x]
   pdf(content)

print(f"Total of {totalHits}")
```

Sample output when running it:

```
LoopReport 09.pdf contains 1999: 44 times.
LoopReport 10.pdf contains 1999: 37 times.
LoopReport 11.pdf contains 1999: 41 times.
LoopReport 12.pdf contains 1999: 46 times.
LoopReport 13.pdf contains 1999: 42 times.
LoopReport 14.pdf contains 1999: 46 times.
LoopReport 15.pdf contains 1999: 42 times.
LoopReport 16.pdf contains 1999: 16 times.
LoopReport 17.pdf contains 1999: 22 times.
LoopReport 18.pdf contains 1999: 23 times.
LoopReport 19.pdf contains 1999: 39 times.
```

Comment: If you want to figure out how to do something, you should *try something*, and if it doesn't work, then you try to figure out the problem - by [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) any error message, and/or [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a

```py
return amountOfHits
```

at the end, outside the try-except clause. And within the except clause either pass or return 0.

And in your for-loop, catch the output into a variable and add it to a total, for example

```py
total = 0
for x in range(len(dirContent)):
   content = dirContent[x]
   total += pdf(content)
```

Comment: But how do i add that to my totalHits?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, your function could return the number of hist which you then add on your totalHits like so :

```
import os
import re
import PyPDF2 as pypdf2

def pdf(name):
   try:
      pdfObject = f"{name}"
      readObject = pypdf2.PdfFileReader(pdfObject)
      pageContent = readObject.getPage(0)
      pageExtract = pageContent.extractText()
      amountOfHits = len(re.findall(rePattern, pageExtract))
      print(f"{pdfObject} contains {rePattern}: "+ str(amountOfHits) + " times.")
   except:
      return 0 # Bare excepts shouldn't be used anyway see E722 
   return amountOfHits # <--- HERE

rePattern = input("Pattern: ")
dirContent = os.listdir()
totalHits = 0
content = ""

for x in range(len(dirContent)):
   content = dirContent[x]
   totalHits += pdf(content) # <--- HERE

print(f"Total of {totalHits}")
```

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks for the Indent ! As for the error handling, it's flawed from the beginning and uses a bare except, while it should catch specific errors instead. But I leave that up to the OP.